# Django ProgrammingError Caused By Model Field

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models

I have a model called "news", defined below:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="news title")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="news content")
    cta = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="news call-to-action")
    mini_image = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="news image helper")
    is_promo = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="promo code")
    promo_benefit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False, default=0.00, verbose_name="promo benefit")
    promo_duration = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0, verbose_name="promo duration")
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And when I try to access a template that uses the news model (whether I'm logged into admin trying to create a new instance or on a custom template), I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/myapp/news/

column omninectar_news.cta does not exist
LINE 1: ...app_news"."title", "myapp_news"."content", "myapp...
                                                             ^
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: how you know ?That it is a Django ProgrammingError Caused By Model Field

Answer (score 0):

```
column omninectar_news.cta does not exist
```

That should be self-explanatory. Your database is out of date.

If you use South, migrate. Otherwise, try to remove the table "omnictar_news" and then run syncdb.

Answer (score 0):

You should to delete the migrations folder and then

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

python manage.py migrate --fake appname
```